# Compile TypeScript on build

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, asp.net-core

I have a ASP.NET Core project (a `.xproj` file) containing some TypeScript files. When I build this project, all `.ts` files are automatically transpiled to `.js` files. Also if I modify and then save a `.ts` file its `.js` is generated (`compileOnSave`). This is nice.

In the same solution I have a .NET Core Class Library (also a `.xproj` file). This project also contains a `tsconfig.json` file and some TypeScript files. The `compileOnSave` feature works nice, but when I build the project, the `.ts` files are not compiled. This means that I need to modify and save the `.ts` file manually to generate the `.js` file.

How do I have to configure my class library project so that `.js` files are created when I build the project?

I'm working with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 with the "TypeScript for Microsoft Visual Studio" version 2.0.6.0 extension installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 
    `<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\DotNet.Web\Microsoft.DotNet.Web.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />`
to the xproj file to get typescript built to JS (got the line from my ASP.NET Core - .xproj file)

Comment: When I open the Property Page of my TypeScript file I cannot set (or see) a build action. Note that I have a .xproj project. Maybe your solution would work for a traditional .csproj project.

Comment: You are right. Setting the Build Action for your typescript file (Solution Browser -> Alt + Return) to "TypeScriptCompile" to get it built, was the pre .net Core / csproj way. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! I'm just not sure if I should remove the existing Microsoft.DotNet.targets when I add the Microsoft.DotNet.Web.targets. At the moment I have both in my .xproj and it works fine :)

Comment: When adding the Microsoft.DotNet.Web.targets, the project type seems to change and also a launchSettings.json gets created. So what I do instead now is adding <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(VSToolsPath)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')"/> to my .jxproj