# compile typescript\ts files as part of build process in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017, tsconfig

In VS2017, I have a WebSite project to which I have added a tsconfig.json file. How should I automate generating js files from ts files as part of build?

I I remove the tsconfig.json file, compile on save option will work but by adding it, even compile on save doesn't work.

An example of tsconfig.json file content:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your tsconfig file to the question?

Comment: Doesn't affect the result, whatever is in the file, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It could be cause by missing typescript in csproj.
If you use NET CORE, this could help [Compile TypeScript on build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41614062/compile-typescript-on-build)

Otherwise create new project and compare csproj configuration with yours to fix typescript.

Comment: There is no csproj, its type is Web Site. In VS, you can create project or web site.

Comment: Csproj is for all .NET projects. If you want to edit it in VS, you have to right click on project and unload it, then right click for edit. You can obser it in the project folder through Total Commander.

Comment: _There is no project file (.csproj or .vbproj). All the files in a folder structure are automatically included in the site._    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the compile on save flag in your tsconfig file to activate compile on save:

```
{
   "compileOnSave": true,
   "compilerOptions": {
       "noImplicitAny" : true
   }
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: Firstly, I tried, it didn't work. Secondly, I need to compile all *.ts once from inside VS.